# In Java how instance of and type cast(i.e (ClassName)) works on proxy object?

Tags: java, proxy, dynamic-proxy

Java generates a proxy class for a given interface and provides the instance of the proxy class. But when we type cast the proxy object to our specific Object, how java handles this internally? Is this treated as special scenario?

For example I have class `OriginalClass` and it implements `OriginalInterface`, when I create proxy object by passing `OriginalInterface` interface Java created proxy class `ProxyClass` using methods in the provided interface and provides object of this class(i.e. `ProxyClass`). If my understanding is correct then can you please answer following queries

1. When I type cast object of `ProxyClass` to my class `OriginalClass` this works, but how Java is allowing this? Same in case of instace of?
2. As my knowledge Java creates a proxy class only with the methods, but what happen when I try to access attributes on this object?
3. Only interface methods are getting implemented in proxy, but what happens when I try to access a method which not in interface and only mentioned in the class?

Thanks,
Student

Comment: Are you shure that casting your proxy to OriginalClass works? In my understanding if you created the proxy for the OriginalInterface you shouldn't be able to cast to OriginalClass

Comment: Great question, and there must be some special casing for proxy types in the casting and instanceof logic. Would love to see the actual code, if anyone knows what part of the JDK source code to look at.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Java isn't allowing casting from a proxy to a concrete class. JDK proxies (`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`) are only proxies of an interface. The resulting proxy is of type `ProxyX` (X being a number), and if you try to cast it to any class you will get `ClassCastException`

Therefore your 2nd and 3rd questions aren't relevant - the proxy isn't backed by a concrete class. To achieve this, you can use other proxying mechanisms - CGLIB or javassist. They use ynamic subclassing, and so all `protected` (and above) fields and methods are accessible to the subclass (proxy).

Comment: Thanks very much for your quick reply. Java is not allowing to cast to concrete class.

Answer (score 8):

From the API javadocs for java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler:

> InvocationHandler is the interface implemented by the invocation handler of a proxy instance.

The dynamic proxy implements the interface, but uses the handler (OriginalClass) to provide the base implementations of the methods.

To answer your questions:

1. The compiler will let you cast as long as it doesn't have enough information to be certain that the cast cannot succeed. The runtime behaviour of casting and instanceof tests for dynamic proxies is described in the javadoc for java.lang.reflect.Proxy. Casts and instanceof tests will succeed if used with interfaces, but not if used with classes.
2. You cannot access any attributes using the dynamic proxy because it implements the interface, it does not extend the handler class.
3. You cannot access any methods not declared in the interface using the dynamic proxy because it implements the interface, it does not extend the handler class.

Inside the implementation of the dynamic proxy (e.g. in the implementation of the invoke(...) method) you can access the members of the handler using reflection.

Here's some test code that I used to check my answer:

```
// package ...;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TestDynamicProxy
{
    @Test
    public void testCast() throws Exception {
        Foo foo = (Foo) TestProxy.newInstance(new FooImpl());
        foo.bar(null);

        System.out.println("Class: " + foo.getClass());
        System.out.println("Interfaces: " + foo.getClass().getInterfaces());

        Assert.assertNotNull(foo);
        Assert.assertTrue(foo instanceof Foo);
        Assert.assertFalse(foo instanceof FooImpl);
    }
}

interface Foo
{
    Object bar(Object obj) throws Exception;
}

class FooImpl implements Foo
{
    public Object bar(Object obj) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
}

class TestProxy implements java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler
{
    private final Object obj;

    public static Object newInstance(Object obj) {
        return java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(obj.getClass().getClassLoader(), obj.getClass().getInterfaces(), new TestProxy(obj));
    }

    private TestProxy(Object obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        Object result;

        try {
            result = m.invoke(obj, args);
        }
        catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw e.getTargetException();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("unexpected invocation exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

This [article](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) has a lot of useful information and example code.

Comment: Very helpful answer -- but the link to "article" is broken, and should be updated to:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html

Comment: @LukeHutchison Thank you for the link to the current (Java SE 11) version of the article. I've edited the answer to replace the broken link to the Sun website.